Is it possible to save my generated officegen file in a seperate folder?
I'm using officegen to generate a word document:
// Your string content
const yourString = aiLog;

// Create a new docx object
const docx = officegen('docx');

// Create a paragraph with your string content
const pObj = docx.createP();
pObj.addText(yourString);

// Generate the Word document
const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('result.docx');
docx.generate(outputStream);

}

... which saves the document in the project folder.
I would want to instead save it in a separate hot folder which ends up printing the document.  Or at least automatically move it from the project folder to the hot folder as soon as it has been created. How would one do this?
